# Golang: How do I determine the number of lines in a file efficiently?

Tags: go

In Golang, I am looking for an efficient way to determine the number of lines a file has.

Of course, I can always loop through the entire file, but does not seem very efficient.

```
file, _ := os.Open("/path/to/filename")
fileScanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
lineCount := 0
for fileScanner.Scan() {
    lineCount++
}
fmt.Println("number of lines:", lineCount)
```

Is there a better (quicker, less expensive) way to find out how many lines a file has?

Comment: Afaik as I know that's the only way, in any language.

Comment: Yup. You can get bytes in constant time, but not lines.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Here's a faster line counter using `bytes.Count` to find the newline characters.

It's faster because it takes away all the extra logic and buffering required to return whole lines, and takes advantage of some assembly optimized functions offered by the bytes package to search characters in a byte slice.

Larger buffers also help here, especially with larger files. On my system, with the file I used for testing, a 32k buffer was fastest.

```
func lineCounter(r io.Reader) (int, error) {
    buf := make([]byte, 32*1024)
    count := 0
    lineSep := []byte{'\n'}

    for {
        c, err := r.Read(buf)
        count += bytes.Count(buf[:c], lineSep)

        switch {
        case err == io.EOF:
            return count, nil

        case err != nil:
            return count, err
        }
    }
}
```

and the benchmark output:

```
BenchmarkBuffioScan   500      6408963 ns/op     4208 B/op    2 allocs/op
BenchmarkBytesCount   500      4323397 ns/op     8200 B/op    1 allocs/op
BenchmarkBytes32k     500      3650818 ns/op     65545 B/op   1 allocs/op
```

Comment: Notice that your code does not catch the possibility that Read() returns some bytes and io.EOF(), which is allowed.

Comment: I think it does, I check for EOF after I count bytes

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I missed that.

Comment: Can you please add an example of how to use the lineCounter function?

Comment: @RogierLommers: what is it you're unsure how to do? lineCounter consumes an io.Reader and returns number of lines. There's not much else to explain.

Comment: Just to add a bit of info, I used this to count a 1.5GB text file and it read through in about 5-10 seconds on my chromebook.

Comment: Try the cases: 1 line (it returns 0). Without enter on last line (returns less 1 line). Please, fix your answer. If people copy without checking, which is common unfortunately, the result will be catastrophic.

if count == 0 && c > 0 {
   count += 1
  }

  count += bytes.Count(buf[:c], lineSep)

Comment: @darionascimento: I stated that this only counts newlines. This also matches the standard behavior of `wc`, which states: `A line is defined as a string of characters delimited by a <newline> character`. If you want a function to count an incomplete line you can do so, but it would make this example a little less clear.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I made [a quick CLI](https://gist.github.com/Hubro/76e6b7c906c308b84b23188578b74483) to benchmark the speed of this function compared with `wc -l`. I tested counting a 1.6 GB log file with 11.6 million lines. The first time I counted the lines using `wc -l` it took several seconds as the file was cached. After that `wc -l` took between 0.387 and 0.422 seconds to count the lines. `./linecounter` counts the file in between 0.407 and 0.425 seconds. Very respectable in my opinion.

Comment: I believe this may be a case of an off-by-1 error. After all, a file with no line separator still always contains a single line, even if it's empty. I guess we're going by the UNIX way of assuming that each file ends with a trailing newline, but I don't think that's universally true and there are non-file `Reader`s as well.

Answer (score 10):

The most efficient way I found is using IndexByte of the byte packet, it is at least four times faster than using `bytes.Count` and depending on the size of the buffer it uses much less memory.

```
func LineCounter(r io.Reader) (int, error) {

    var count int
    const lineBreak = '\n'

    buf := make([]byte, bufio.MaxScanTokenSize)

    for {
        bufferSize, err := r.Read(buf)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            return 0, err
        }

        var buffPosition int
        for {
            i := bytes.IndexByte(buf[buffPosition:], lineBreak)
            if i == -1 || bufferSize == buffPosition {
                break
            }
            buffPosition += i + 1
            count++
        }
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
    }

    return count, nil
}
```

Benchmark

```
BenchmarkIndexByteWithBuffer  2000000          653 ns/op        1024 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkBytes32k             500000          3189 ns/op       32768 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

Comment: You have a bug in that `io.Reader.Read` can return non-zero and `io.EOF` at the same time and in this case you miss counting the newlines.

Comment: I hadn't noticed, thanks @DuncanHarris
It's solved.

Answer (score 1):

I tested all the methods in this GitHub repo https://github.com/christiangda/go-line-counter, and the fastest is the algorithm of [@JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb)

```bash
goos: darwin
goarch: arm64
pkg: github.com/christiangda/go-line-counter
BenchmarkScannerLineCounter-10                      1000              9673 ns/op            4096 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkScannerLineCounter-10                      1000             10290 ns/op            4096 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkScannerLineCounter-10                      1000             10065 ns/op            4096 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkScannerLineCounter-10                      1000             10238 ns/op            4096 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkScannerLineCounter-10                      1000             10059 ns/op            4096 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkJimBLineCounter-10                         1000              5063 ns/op           32770 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkJimBLineCounter-10                         1000              4935 ns/op           32768 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkJimBLineCounter-10                         1000              4866 ns/op           32768 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkJimBLineCounter-10                         1000              4755 ns/op           32768 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkJimBLineCounter-10                         1000              4665 ns/op           32768 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkDanielCastilloLineCounter-10               1000             11395 ns/op           65536 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkDanielCastilloLineCounter-10               1000             11601 ns/op           65536 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkDanielCastilloLineCounter-10               1000             11119 ns/op           65536 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkDanielCastilloLineCounter-10               1000             11360 ns/op           65536 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkDanielCastilloLineCounter-10               1000             11074 ns/op           65536 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkFuzLineCounter-10                          1000             11791 ns/op            8192 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkFuzLineCounter-10                          1000             11560 ns/op            8192 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkFuzLineCounter-10                          1000             11575 ns/op            8192 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkFuzLineCounter-10                          1000             11607 ns/op            8192 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkFuzLineCounter-10                          1000             11636 ns/op            8192 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
ok      github.com/christiangda/go-line-counter 0.553s
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no approach that is significantly faster than yours as there is no meta-data on how many lines a file has. You could reach a little speed up by manually looking for newline-characters:

```
func lineCount(r io.Reader) (int n, error err) {
    buf := make([]byte, 8192)

    for {
        c, err := r.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF && c == 0 {
                break
            } else {
                return
            }
        }

        for _, b := range buf[:c] {
            if b == '\n' {
                n++
            }
        }
    }

    if err == io.EOF {
        err = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if this would work on windows.. you could have \n but not \r\n right ?

Comment: it will work fine on windows since it there will always be `\n`.

Comment: this is actually a bit slower than using `bufio.Scanner`. Replacing the for range loop with `bytes.Count` speeds it up considerably though (bytes.Count has an ASM version of IndexByte)