# Count lines via bufio

Tags: go

I'm utilizing bufio to do a for loop for each line in a text file. I have no idea how to count the amount of lines though.

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(bufio.NewReader(file))
```

The above is what I use to scan my file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
counter := 0
for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    counter++
    // do something with your line
}
fmt.Printf("Lines read: %d", counter)
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a built in method by bufio, but I guess i'll just use that instead. The only issue is, I wanna display the amount of lines before I run a the for loops contents.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24563853/1078890) answer, that might help with that.

Comment: @Sladey In order to find out how many lines a file has, you have to read through the entire thing. This is something you can't change.

Comment: This does not handle files with very long lines. You will get bufio.Scanner: token too long

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and fast. No need for buffering, `scanner` already does that. Don't do unnecessary `string` conversions. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func lineCount(filename string) (int64, error) {
    lc := int64(0)
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    s := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for s.Scan() {
        lc++
    }
    return lc, s.Err()
}

func main() {
    filename := `testfile`
    lc, err := lineCount(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(filename+" line count:", lc)
}
```

Comment: Of course, you could simplify the end of `lineCount` to just `return lc, s.Err()`.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, the accepted answer fails at long lines. The default limit is `bufio.MaxScanTokenSize` which is 64KiB. So if your line is longer than 65536 chars, it will silently fail. You've got two options.

1. Call `scanner.Buffer()` and supply the sufficient `max` parameter. `buffer` may be small by default because `Scanner` is smart enough to allocate new ones. Can be a problem if you don't know the total size beforehand, like with vanilla `Reader` interface, and you've got **huge** lines - the memory consumption will grow correspondingly as `Scanner` records all the line.
2. Recreate `scanner` in the outer loop, this will ensure that you advance further:

```
var scanner *bufio.Scanner
counter := 0
for scanner == nil || scanner.Err() == bufio.ErrTooLong {
    scanner = bufio.NewScanner(reader)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        counter++
    }
}
```

The problem with (2) is that you keep allocating and deallocating buffers instead of reusing them. So let's fuse (1) and (2):

```
var scanner *bufio.Scanner
buffer := make([]byte, bufio.MaxScanTokenSize)
counter := 0
for scanner == nil || scanner.Err() == bufio.ErrTooLong {
    scanner = bufio.NewScanner(reader)
    scanner.Buffer(buffer, 0)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        counter++
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my approach to do the task:

```
inputFile, err := os.Open("input.txt")

if err != nil {
    panic("Error happend during opening the file. Please check if file exists!")
    os.Exit(1)
}

defer inputFile.Close()

inputReader := bufio.NewReader(inputFile)

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(inputReader)
// Count the words.
count := 0
for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", line)
    count++
}
if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading input:", err)
}
fmt.Printf("%d\n", count)
```

Comment: Don't use `panic`+`os.Exit` for non-programming errors (and then hide the actual reason for the error!). You could have just done `log.Fatal(err)`.