# How to read specific line of file?

Tags: go

I need to read specific line of file. Some of related topics I've read: [golang: How do I determine the number of lines in a file efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562942/golang-how-do-i-determine-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file-efficiently), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692567/what-is-the-best-way-to-count-lines-in-file

I've write the following function and it works as expected, but I have doubt: may be there is better (efficient) way?

```
func ReadLine(r io.Reader, lineNum int) (line string, lastLine int, err error) {
    sc := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for sc.Scan() {
        lastLine++
        if lastLine == lineNum {
            return sc.Text(), lastLine, sc.Err()
        }
    }
    return line, lastLine, io.EOF
}
```

Comment: You have no idea how to do it, but you have written code that does what you want?

Comment: Yep, you are right. My english isn't quite good)

Comment: Your solution looks great. I would not change it, unless you are looking to do something special [so for example, if you want to be able to quickly find a line on demand, say from a client requesting data, DB style, you could consider caching the entire file in memory inside a slice, and then you could simply grab the line by using the index as the line number]

Comment: Thank for advice. Could you explain what does it mean "you could consider caching the entire file in memory inside a slice, and then you could simply grab the line by using the index as the line number" in the square brackets of your comment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two people said my code in question is actual solution. So I've posted it here. Thanks to @orcaman for additional advice.

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "io"
)

func ReadLine(r io.Reader, lineNum int) (line string, lastLine int, err error) {
    sc := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for sc.Scan() {
        lastLine++
        if lastLine == lineNum {
            // you can return sc.Bytes() if you need output in []bytes
            return sc.Text(), lastLine, sc.Err()
        }
    }
    return line, lastLine, io.EOF
}
```