# bufio.NewScanner(r) calling Scan() drain buffer from r

Tags: go, io

I want to create 2 scanners from the same reader `r`. But when calling `Scan()` from the first scanner, it drains the buffer from `r`, so the second scanner is reading a zero buffer. Is that a common behavior? How to fix it so that the second scanner properly reads from the original `r`?

```
r := bytes.NewReader([]byte("ninebytes"))
fmt.Println(r.Len()) // 9
sc1 := bufio.NewScanner(r)
sc1.Scan()
fmt.Printf("scanner1: %s\n", sc1.Text()) // scanner1: ninebytes

// i want create new scanner from r too
fmt.Println(r.Len()) // 0
sc2 := bufio.NewScanner(r)
sc1.Scan()
fmt.Printf("scanner2: %s\n", sc2.Text()) // scanner2:
```

Here's an example at [play golang](https://play.golang.org/p/v0g7C4qA8Nh)

This is what I'm trying to do: read a specific line from a file, but when calling the function a second time, `r` is drained.

```
func readLineScanner(r io.Reader, lineNum int) ([]byte, error) {
    sc := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    lastLine := 0
    for sc.Scan() {
        lastLine++
        if lastLine == lineNum {
            break
        }
    }
    return sc.Bytes(), sc.Err()
}
```

Comment: It's the expected behavior. What are you trying to accomplish? The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Scanner scan r and split it using newline, I want used that fact to read specific line from file like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693421/how-to-read-specific-line-of-file, and then benchmark it with io.ReederAt and io.Seeker.

Comment: r.Seek(0, 0) do the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Reading a reader is in general a destructive action; particularly with http request bodies.

Instead you can create a tee reader, which is modelled on the unix `tee` command.

[Link to the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#example_TeeReader)

Modifying the example you've given:

```
r := bytes.NewReader([]byte("ninebytes"))

var buf bytes.Buffer
tee := io.TeeReader(r, &buf)

sc1 := bufio.NewScanner(tee)
sc1.Scan()
fmt.Printf("scanner1: %s\n", sc1.Text())

sc2 := bufio.NewScanner(&buf)
sc2.Scan()
fmt.Printf("scanner2: %s\n", sc2.Text())
```

Using a tee reader, as you read from `r` it will write a copy of those bytes to `buf`, which you can use again in the second scanner.