# How to read specific number of lines of a file?

Tags: go

I need to read specific lines of a file at one time (for example, 10 lines one time), and read from the next line (11) of last read position next time I read the file, and continue to read 10 lines.

Comment: Hello, what did you try ?

Comment: I've read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693421/how-to-read-specific-line-of-file, but have no idea of how to read from the last line number at next time read.

Answer (score 0):

There's no available library function to read specific number of lines. Although
you can implement something like this to do the same. Working example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/G1Ww4cWlIqW)

```
func readLines(n int, r io.Reader) ([]string, error) {
    rd := bufio.NewReader(r)

    var (
        lines = make([]string, 0, n)
        bs    []byte
        done  bool
    )

    for {
        if done || len(lines) == n {
            break
        }

        bss, isPrefix, err := rd.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                return nil, err
            }

            done = true
        }

        bs = append(bs, bss...)

        if isPrefix {
            continue
        }

        lines = append(lines, string(bs))
        bs = make([]byte, 0)
    }

    return lines, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I wrote, and seems it works

```
func ReadLine(inputFile io.ReadSeeker, startPos int64, lineNum int) (slice []string, lastPos int64, err error) {
    r := bufio.NewReader(inputFile)
    var line string
    inputFile.Seek(startPos, os.SEEK_SET)
    lastPos = startPos
    for i := 0; i < lineNum; i++ {
        line, err = r.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        lastPos += int64(len(line))
        slice = append(slice, line)
    }
    return
}
```