# How to approach GNU's "wc -l" speed with Go (golang)?

Tags: performance, go, mmap

I am trying to catch GNU's wc -l speed at counting lines. I would be satisfied being 1.5-2 times slower. The best I could do is 4 times slower. The code using syscall.Mmap:

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime/pprof"
    "syscall"
)

const (
    DATA_READ int64 = 4096 * 4096
)

var cpuprofile = flag.String("cpuprofile", "", "write cpu profile to file")

func main() {
    flag.Usage = func() {
        fmt.Printf("Usage: %s [options] <file>\n\n", os.Args[0])
        flag.PrintDefaults()
    }
    flag.Parse()
    if len(flag.Args()) != 1 {
        flag.Usage()
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    file_path := flag.Args()[0]

    if *cpuprofile != "" {
        profile, err := os.Create(*cpuprofile)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        pprof.StartCPUProfile(profile)
        defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()
    }

    // Open file for reading
    file, err := os.OpenFile(file_path, os.O_RDONLY, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fi, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    file_size := fi.Size()
    fd := int(file.Fd())
    defer file.Close()

    line_counter := 0
    read_from := int64(0)
    for {
        read_size := DATA_READ
        if (file_size - read_from) < read_size {
            read_size = file_size - read_from
        }
        if read_size == 0 {
            break
        }
        data, err := syscall.Mmap(
            fd, read_from, int(read_size),
            syscall.PROT_READ, syscall.MAP_PRIVATE)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        for _, char := range data {
            if char == '\n' {
                line_counter += 1
            }
        }
        err = syscall.Munmap(data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        read_from += int64(len(data))
    }
    fmt.Println(line_counter)
}
```

Straightforward approach, read large chunks into buffer, straight.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

const BUF_SIZE = 4096 * 4096

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        fmt.Printf("Usage: %s <file>\n\n", os.Args[0])
        os.Exit(-1)
    }

    file, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    buf := make([]byte, BUF_SIZE)
    line_counter := 0

    for {
        bytes_read, err := file.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            } else {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        }

        for i := 0; i < bytes_read; i++ {
            if buf[i] == '\n' {
                line_counter += 1
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(line_counter)
}
```

The test file was generated with the python script:

```python
import os
data = ' '*80 + '\n'
data *= 1000000
with open(os.environ['HOME'] + '/data', 'w') as dest:
    for i in range(70):
        dest.write(data)
        dest.flush()
```

Timings:

```
$ time ./main ~/data
70000000

real    0m3.965s
user    0m3.768s
sys     0m0.196s


$ time ./straight ~/data

70000000

real    0m5.180s
user    0m4.432s
sys     0m0.748s


$ time wc -l ~/data
70000000 /home/<user>/data

real    0m0.947s
user    0m0.440s
sys     0m0.504s
```

I tried to profile my main.go program:

```
./main -cpuprofile main.prof ~/data
go tool pprof ./main main.prof
```

Results weren't helpful for me. It is also interesting main.go is faster than straight.go in both user and sys departments. Looks like index, value := range doesn't make range checking (user) and mmap is indeed faster than a plain Read (sys and user). Still, the fastest program I did is 4 times slower than a "wc -l", which only does getc(fp).

I wonder is there anything else I could do to approach the speed of old good wc?

upd: was wrong about getc, the real wc from coreutils uses safe_read, which is essentialy a wrapper over the plain read.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562942/golang-how-do-i-determine-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file-efficiently/24563853#24563853

Comment: Thank you @JimB
This works indeed: execution time dropped to the wc's speed, down to .9-1s.